# get items from database with minimum records

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select 10 customers with minimum number of records(purchases).
My tables are: products, customers, purchases(id, customer_id, product_id).
What i think is to select customers, group them and then write a nested query and get the minimum count, like this:

```
            SELECT last_name, name, COUNT(pur.id) FROM customers AS c 
            INNER JOIN purchases AS pur ON c.id=pur.customer_id 
            INNER JOIN products AS pr ON pr.id=pur.product_id 
            GROUP BY last_name, name 
            HAVING count(pur.id) =  (SELECT min(pur.id) FROM 
               (SELECT count(pur.id) FROM customers AS c
               INNER JOIN purchases AS pur ON c.id=pur.customer_id
               INNER JOIN products AS pr ON pr.id=pur.product_id
               GROUP BY last_name, name))
```

But i'm not sure how to go about it?

Comment: This is a quite general sql question so stackoverflow.com would be a better site for the question. dba.stackexchange.com is more for questions for administering the databases.

Comment: @LauriK - SQL questions are on-topic here!

Comment: Thanks @Vérace, that's good to know, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close actually. You must first group by person and count the purcases. Then sort by the count and select 10 first persons.

One detail missing from the question. You said that you want minimum number of purchases. In the database schema one purchase contains many products. The sample query counts the total count of the products in all the purchases. In my solution this is the same. If you are interested only about the purchases just drop the join to the products table.

```sql
SELECT 
  last_name,
  name,
  purchase_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      last_name,
      name,
      count(pur.id) purchase_count
    FROM customers AS c
    JOIN purchases AS pur ON c.id=pur.customer_id
    JOIN products AS pr ON pr.id=pur.product_id
    GROUP BY last_name, name
  ) tota_purchase_counts
ORDER BY purchase_count
LIMIT 10
;
```